# Datepicker Angular Material filter validation

Tags: angular, angular-material

Could someone guide me to (if possible) how to prevent the user from booking certain dates?

I manage to prevent clicking on the previous dates and the end date of the contract but not the dates of unavailability.
[image]

In my database I store dates (start date, end date) for employees.

How can I prevent the user from clicking dates when he wants to book a session with one of my employees?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at the [API documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api#MatDatepickerInput), especially the `max/min` inputs.

Comment: Hello, I already use [min] and [max] for the duration of the contract of my employees, but I do not know how to add also the dates of unavailability (leave, illness) :-/

Comment: I don't think you should use a single date picker for every case : use one picker by case (one for leave/illness, one for vacations, one for work ...)

Comment: The problem is that to make a reservation (for the client), I need only one calendar :-/

Comment: Then use a validator to state that the date is not available, making the form invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[matDatepickerFilter]="myFilter"**

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5el3w9)

```
myFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {

        let date: any;
        let month: any;

        if (d.getDate().toString().length < 2) {
            date = '0' + d.getDate().toString()
        } else {
            date = d.getDate().toString()
        }

        if ((d.getMonth() + 1).toString().length < 2) {
            month = '0' + (d.getMonth() + 1).toString()
        } else {
            month = (d.getMonth() + 1).toString()
        }

        const day = d.getFullYear().toString() + "-" + month + "-" + date;

        return !this.disableDateList.includes(day);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="col-md-6">
     <input matInput [matDatepickerFilter]="myFilter" [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="date"
                        placeholder="Choose date">
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker picker touchUi="true"></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Thank you @UnluckyAj, this is exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: please accept an vote up if solution helped so others can find it easily.

Comment: With pleasure !

Comment: Stackblitz not found

Comment: Important to note: leave it as a variable (myFilter) instead of refactoring it to a method/function. Otherwise the this keyword goes out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[min]` and `[max]` for this.

**Component.html**

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Component.ts**

```
minDate = new Date(2000, 0, 1);
maxDate = new Date(2020, 0, 1);
```

Comment: Hello, I already use [min] and [max] for the duration of the contract of my employees, but I do not know how to add also the dates of unavailability (leave, illness)